# CanvasPixelArray - how many index spots for one color value?

Tags: html, html5-canvas

For a personal project, I'm re-implementing some Javascript code to Java.  One particular thing that is tripping me up at this point is whether a Color is represented by three or four index values in the [HTML5 CanvasPixelArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff975056%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) object.

The page linked above states that an offset value of 4 is used.  However, one graphic effect that I'm re-implementing has this function:

```
function getPixelValue(x, y) {
  var offset = (x + y * width) * 4;
  var r = imageData[offset];
  var g = imageData[offset + 1];
  var b = imageData[offset + 2];

  return ( ((255 << 8) | r) << 8 | g) << 8 | b;
}
```

to return an color integer value for a given pixel.  The code works in the browser, but I'm confused by the fact that `r, g, b` are all contained in a given 3 block segment of the array, while `offset` is 4.  This same value for offset is shown in the code example at the page linked above.

What is the reason for the difference?  If a pixel color value is contained within a 3 block segment, shouldn't `offset` include 3 as a constant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Canvas **always** returns RGBA but you can skip the alpha channel (index 3) if you don't need it but will always have to skip 4 positions in the byte array.

Typically for photos the alpha value is always 255 (non-transparent) so it isn't needed. For other types of graphics which already contain an alpha channel (for example PNG icons etc.) the alpha channel becomes more important.

Your `getPixelValue` simply ignores the alpha channel and returns the RGB value independent on the value of the alpha channel (which is correct when you want a *color* value from the source - the color value (from source) will be the same regardless of the alpha value).